# What would be the best way to make this image interactive

Tags: html, canvas, hyperlink, html5-canvas

I need to create a wheel like this, which can have links on each section that you can click on. The wheel itself can be an image but I need to be able to have links for each section so I don't know if its possible to do some sort of overlay?

[image]

Would some sort of HTML5 Canvas be best for this or is there another way?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: **Primarily opinion-based** _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: And image map or canvas would likely work the best

Answer (score 0):

Check out HTML `<map>` elements. The shape attribute also supports polygons if you need more complex shapes.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: Yeah, this is the only thing I know of but didn't know if it was a bit "old fashioned" now and if if there was a more modern browser friendly version?